# Modx Evolution: How to access and modify a template variable (tv) before save?

Tags: php, plugins, modx, modx-evolution

Not a big fan of modx, but sadly it's what we use in work.

I'm having trouble saving a modified template variable in modx evolution (1.0.5).

In my plugin, called with the OnBeforeDocFormSave event, I'm doing this to get and modify the tv:

```
//include global variables
global $content,$default_template,$tmplvars;

$foo = $tmplvars[$TV_ID][1] . "bar";

$tmplvars[$TV_ID][1] = $foo;
```

This doesn't appear to work. $foo is set but the tv isn't saved.

$TV_ID is the resource ID of the template variable I'm after.

There are numerous ways to get the TV with API calls, but how do I modify it before it's saved?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It's a shame you're not a fan, modx is easily my favourite CMS of those I've used (Drupal, Wordpress, Joomla)

Comment: not a fan of cmses in general :) give me a nice framework any day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution appears to work:

Called by the plugin on the OnBeforeDocFormSave event

```
//include global variables
global $content,$default_template,$tmplvars;

$foo = $tmplvars[$TV_ID][1] . "bar";

$tmplvars[$TV_ID][0] = $TV_ID; //added this line
$tmplvars[$TV_ID][1] = $foo;
```

where $TV_ID is the id of the Template Variable you are trying to modify.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Evo ot Revo?

I update a page counter in revo using a plugin on the OnWebPageComplete event like this:

```
<?php

$docID = $modx->resource->get('id'); //get the page id

$tvId = 9; //the tv id I want to change

$tv = $modx->getObject('modTemplateVar',$tvId); // get the obj.

$tv->setValue($docID, $tv->getValue($docID) + 1 ); // set it's new value

$tv->save(); // save the new value
```

-sean

Comment: hmmm - sorry, I don't know what the evolution syntax would be - have you tried posting in the modx community forums or checking out rtfm.modx.com?